# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key playPressed.'

Tags: xcode5, uncaught-exception

I know that there has been threads with a similar topic, but I am using Xcode 5 and there is no XIB-File with a wrong reference in my project. I tried to create a simple soundboard, I really cannot figure out what the problem is.

```
<pre>//  ViewController.h
//  AudioPlayer
//
//  Created by Marvin on 30.11.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Marvin. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
- (IBAction)playPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender;

@end

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
//  ViewController.m
//  AudioPlayer
//
//  Created by Marvin on 30.11.13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Marvin. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player = _player;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Playstation" ofType:@"mp3"]];
    self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)playPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.player play];
}

- (IBAction)stopPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.player stop];
}

- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = sender;
    self.player.volume = slider.value;

}
@end
```

[image]

Comment: check if there is more then one instance in file owner

Comment: thanks, I figured it out! I had to remove old outlets 
http://www.pic-upload.de/view-21487287/Bildschirmfoto-2013-11-30-um-18.16.44.png.html

Comment: that is exactly what i was saying if you view my last comment..

Comment: bro you can also up-vote my comment as appreciation... that's make some repute of mine as well

Comment: I really would love to upvote ur comment, but I'm afraid I have not enough rep for that, this is my first post, just opened the account today, but I will do so as soon as I am allowed to.

Comment: :) so its due.. best of luck